# Dart - 'no such type' when attempting to extend a class

Tags: dart

I'm attempting to make a simple program in order to play around with Dart.
When attempting to extend Vec2 with Circle, I receive an error message stating that 'no such type' exist Vec2

I have a structure such that:

Inside geom/geom.dart

```
#library("geom");

#import("dart:math", prefix:'Math');

#source("Vec2.dart");
#source("Circle.dart");
```

**With two simple classes**

Inside geom/Vec2.dart

```
class Vec2 {
    num x;
    num y;
}
```

Inside geom/Circle.dart

```
class Circle extends Vec2 {
    num radius;
    Circle(this.radius) : super();
}
```

What is the correct way to subclass in Dart? Must the Classes both exist in the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, I just tested with Editor Version 0.1.0.201210010959, build 13075 and in Editor Version Version 0.1.0.201210082015, build 13393. You are allowed to create one class per file if that is what you wish to do.  (Note, Dart does not require one class per file.)

Have you double checked your paths? Please paste in your version number and perhaps a screenshot. Better yet, provide a link to your directory.

Comment: It doesn't work in 13303. That is to say, it will run, but it gives error messages in the editor window. I think it's a recently introduced bug, and hopefully fixed soon.

Comment: Is there a bug? This seems to work in Editor Version 0.1.0.201210020832, build 13122

Comment: Just tested on Version 0.1.0.201210082015, build 13393 and it seems to be working.